# how to get the selected item from list-group in angular 2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, listitem

I'm using bootstrap to display list of items in angular 2.

```
<div class="dialog">
        <header>
            <div class="title"><b>Select a Program</b></div>
            <div class="exit-button" (click)="onClickedExit()"><b>x</b>
</div>
        </header>

        <div class="bs-example">
            <div class="list-group" (click)="onClickedItem()">
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-
        item-action" active>Pictures</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-
        item-action">Documents</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-
        item-action">Music</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-
        item-action">Videos</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Now when user select any one of the item from above list, I want that selected item value. 
This is the code in my component class.

```
      onClickedItem() {
         var items = document.getElementsByClassName("list-group-item 
     active");
    if(items != undefined && items.length === 1) {
         console.log("selected item is:", items[0]);
    }

    }
```

I'm getting undefined as selected value. 
Please suggest the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Youe can use the Template Reference from Angular:
Check this out: [documantion](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#expression-context)

```
    <div class="bs-example">
        <div class="list-group" (click)="onClickedItem(pic)">
            <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-
    item-action" active #pic>Pictures</button>
    </div>




  onClickedItem(ref: any) {
     let items = ref.value;

     if(items != undefined && items.length === 1) {
          console.log("selected item is:", items[0]);
     }
  }
```

Comment: getting undefined value for 'ref' in the method definiton

Comment: log the ref variable to make sure if you get the dom element.... did you add #pic ?

Comment: I haven like this
<div class="bs-example">
            <div class="list-group" (click)="onClickedItem()">
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" active #pic>Pictures</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" #doc>Documents</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" #music>Music</button>
                <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" #vid>Videos</button>
            </div>
        </div>

Comment: ref is also coming as undefined

Comment: The Problem simple.. you need to put the template ref as an parameter into the method onClickedItem(pic)

Comment: I forgot to pass pic in function call() after passing the pic I'm able to see the dom element.

Comment: How do I get the value from that dom element?